# WCF File Upload Large File

Tags: wcf

I've been doing a fair bit of research over the last two days to find a solution to my problem but to no avail.

I have created a WCF service like so:

```
[OperationContract]
void CopyMemberFile(string memberNumber, string fileName, byte[] fileBytes);
```

And I call it from my client like so from a page_load event:

```
byte[] filebytes = null;

using (Stream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
     fs.Read(filebytes, (int)0, (int)fs.Length);
}

client.CopyMemberFile(memberNumber, Path.GetFileName(file), filebytes);
```

My configuration is like so:

Client Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="300" cookieless="UseUri" />
  </authentication>
  <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile>
    <properties>
      <add name="FirstName"/>
      <add name="LastName"/>
      <add name="MemberNumber"/>
      <add name="LastVisit" type="System.DateTime"/>
    </properties>
    <providers>
      <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
      <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
             applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" 
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" />
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" 
         type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="online.members.asp.Services.MembersOnlineSeviceAjaxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="online.members.asp.Services.MembersOnlineSeviceAjax">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="online.members.asp.Services.MembersOnlineSeviceAjaxAspNetAjaxBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="online.members.asp.Services.MembersOnlineSeviceAjax" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMembershipApplications" 
                     closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                     openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                     sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                     allowCookies="false" 
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     messageEncoding="Text" 
                     textEncoding="utf-8" 
                     transferMode="Buffered"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                     proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                   algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:58119/MembershipApplications.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMembershipApplications"
              contract="MembershipApplicationsServiceReference.IMembershipApplications"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IMembershipApplications" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
3/02/2013 11:12:39 AM: Upload.aspx Error: The remote server returned an unexpect
ed response: (400) Bad Request.
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResp
onse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factor
y, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpCha
nnelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeS
pan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message messag
e, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at online.members.asp.MembershipApplicationsServiceReference.IMembershipAppli
cations.CopyMemberFile(String memberNumber, String fileName, Byte[] fileBytes)`
```

I can upload files at only a few KB each but any larger than say 8KB and thing just fails

Any help would be fantastic.

Calling code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = Request.Form["name"];            
    var memberNumber = Request.Form["memberNumber"];
    var tempId = Guid.NewGuid();

    var client = new MembershipApplicationsServiceReference.MembershipApplicationsClient();

    client.LogEvent("Entered Upload.aspx");

    try
    {
        byte[] filebytes = null;

        using (Stream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(filebytes, (int)0, (int)fs.Length);

            client.LogEvent("Starting service call from Upload.aspx");
            client.CopyMemberFile(memberNumber, Path.GetFileName(file), filebytes);                    
        }

        client.LogEvent("Completed service call from Upload.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

        client.LogEvent("Upload.aspx Error: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        client.LogEvent("Finishing up");
    }
}
```

Comment: The message is - The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CopyMemberFile'. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 45385.

Comment: Can you post the complete service model sections of both your service and your client config files?  It sounds like your client is using the default limit (which is a few K).  Also, you might want to look into streaming for WCF for large files.

Comment: Please past your client web.config in your question - code and XML do not show up well in comments :)

Comment: just added, takes some getting used too.

Comment: your first statement has prompt me to beleive i am missing my server side configuration, thereby defaulting to standard?

Comment: How would configure the client congiguration?

Comment: Looking at the configs, it looks like (as you said) you're service doesn't have anything specified for the binding, so it is using the default values.  If you add the BasicHttpBinding from your client config to your service config it should resolve your error.  Your client config looks fine.

Comment: im still having an issue. I might try and go back to the channel factory to impliment runtime configuration.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to create the client?  Are you adding it via a service reference, or doing it via code?

Comment: yes service reference is being used which i think is just a channel proxy.

Comment: Upload your large file by portions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your service's config file, you're using .NET 4.0 and you're not specifying any binding, so you're going to receive the default settings for `basicHttpBinding`.  As suggested in the comments above, update your config file for your service like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMembershipApplications" 
                     closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                     openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                     sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                     allowCookies="false" 
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     messageEncoding="Text" 
                     textEncoding="utf-8" 
                     transferMode="Buffered"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                     proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                   algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="YourServiceName">
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMembershipApplications" 
                contract="YourFullyQualifiedContractName" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

This will tell WCF to use your settings for the `basicHttpBinding` rather than the .NET defaults.

Alternatively, you can omit the `name` attribute on the binding definition and WCF will use it as the default binding for all services handled by the config file (if you have more than one).

If that doesn't help, or if you're getting a different error now, let us know and we'll take it from there.